# How do I capture named groups in C# .NET regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use named groups to parse a string.

An example input is:

```
exitcode: 0; session id is RDP-Tcp#2
```

and my attempted regex is:

```
("(exitCode)+(\s)*:(\s)*(?<exitCode>[^;]+)(\s)*;(\s)*(session id is)(\s)*(?<sessionID>[^;]*)(\s)*");
```

Where is my syntax wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What have you tried? What does your C# code look like? What is the problem - do you get an error (if so: what is it??) or does it just not return any data, or what ??

Comment: Which groups do you need to capture? The exit code and the session ID?

Comment: Please also post the results you expect to get, and the ones you actually are getting.

Comment: Four downvotes and four votes to close? Seriously? It's a little messy, but there's a *clear* question here, and it's not unusual for a newbie to not know how to format.

Comment: @Peter Broughton: I fully agree with that, we shoudn't demotivate our fellow users like this but motivate them to work on their questions instead by providing positive feedback.

Answer (score 3):

In your example:

```
exitcode: 0; session id is RDP-Tcp#2
```

It does not end with a semi-colon, but it seems your regular expression expects a semi-colon to mark the end of sessionID:

```
(?<sessionID>[^;]*)
```

I notice that immediately following both your named groups, you have optional whitespace matches -- perhaps it would help to add whitespace into the character classes, like this:

```
(?<exitCode>[^;\s]+)
(?<sessionID>[^;\s]*)
```

Even better, split the string on the semi-colon first, and then perhaps you don't even need a regular expression.  You'd have these two substrings after you split on the semi-colon, and the exitcode and sessionID happen to be on the ends of the strings, making it easy to parse them any number of ways:

```
exitcode: 0
session id is RDP-Tcp#2
```

Answer (score 0):

Richard's answer really covers it already - either remove or make optional the semicolon at the end and it should work, and definitely consider putting whitespace in the negated classes or just splitting on semi-colon, but a little extra food for thought. :)

Don't bother with \s where it's not necessary - looks like your output is some form of log or something, so it should be more predictable, and if so something simpler can do:

```
exitcode: (?<exitCode>\d+);\s+session id is\s+(?<sessionID>[^;\s]*);?
```

For the splitting on semi-colon, you'll get an array of two objects - here's some pseudo-code, assuming exitcode is numeric and sessionid doesn't have spaces in:

```
splitresult = input.split('\s*;\s*')
exitCode  = splitresult[0].match('\d+')
sessionId = splitresult[1].match('\S*$')
```

Depending on who will be maintaining the code, this might be considered more readable than the above expression.